# Getting error when trying to run make on a github repo windows 10

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin

When I try to compile this program, I get the following error, and I cannot find out how to resolve it..
I tried `make -DCC=gcc` I got this from another post when I tried googling the problem, but didn't help instead it gives me another error message

```
PS \massdns> make
mkdir -p bin
cc  -O3 -std=c11 -DHAVE_EPOLL -DHAVE_SYSINFO -Wall -fstack-protector-strong main.c -o bin/massdns
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -O3 -std=c11 -DHAVE_EPOLL -DHAVE_SYSINFO -Wall -fstack-protector-strong main.c -o bin/massdns, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

Error message from make `-DCC=gcc`

```
PS massdns> make -DCC=gcc
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\install\bin\make (pid = 4284)
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\make\tools\install\bin\make is suspending for 30 seconds...done sleep(30). Continuing.
make: *** C=gcc: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Been trying to solve this for awhile so if anyone could help, it would be greatly appertained

---

Repo says to install this, do this

```
Clone the git repository and cd into the project root folder. Then run make to build from source. If you are not on Linux, run make nolinux. On Windows, the Cygwin packages gcc-core, git and make are required.
```

---

Edit: I did try the make nolinux command just forgot I did because i've been trying to do this for awhile, it's the same output, heres the output

```
PS massdns> make nolinux
mkdir -p bin
cc  -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -fstack-protector-strong main.c -o bin/massdns
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -O3 -std=c11 -Wall -fstack-protector-strong main.c -o bin/massdns, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:11: nolinux] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you try the command `make nolinux`?

Comment: @rfmodulator Yes, sorry I forgot I did, I updated it with the output in the post.

Comment: You might try `make V=1 nolinux` to get verbose output. There are other arguments that can be passed to `make` that will show different levels of verbosity as well. ...idea here is to figure out which file it can't find.

Comment: @rfmodulator Thanks for trying to help. I figured it out it was my fault, of course. again thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, of course a user error.

Wasn't familiar with how you installed the packages, gcc-core, git via the Cygwin installer as it's a very unique interaction I haven't seen on an installer. I also had to do `git clone repo_url` inside the Cygwin terminal and also had to run `make` directory inside the Cygwin Terminal asweell.

Comment: all cygwin tools work better from the Cygwin Terminal. Some does not work at all from CMD due to the presence of link